# There is "undefined" in my chart created by chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

There is an undefined appearing in the chart created by Chart.js v3.7.0 and v2.9.4 as well ass seen in the figure. [My Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKiLV.png)

and the function generating the graph, div and canvas is (JS) as follows:

```js
    function arrangeForGraph(counts){
        for(var i =0;i<counts.length;i++){
                var divname = document.createElement("div");
                divname.id="div"+i;
                divname.class="chartAreaWrapper;chart";
        var dataname = document.createElement("data");
                var _canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                _canvas.id="canvas"+i;
                _canvas.height="400";
                _canvas.width="600";
                _label_list = counts[i][4];
        dataname.id=_label_list;
        dataname.value= counts[i][0];
        dataname.style="display:none;"
        dataname.title="countchart"; 
        dataname.text="countsch";
                var ctx = _canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
        Chart.plugins.register({id: 'pan', id:'zoom'});
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: _label_list,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "Upper Bound",
                                data: counts[i][3],
                                backgroundColor: ['rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.50)'],
                                borderColor: ['rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.50)'],
                                borderWidth: 0.5,
                                pointRadius: 1,
                                fill: 1,
                            },
                            {
                                label: "Lower Bound",
                                data: counts[i][1],
                                backgroundColor: ['rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.50)'],
                                borderColor: ['rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.50)'],
                                borderWidth: 0.5,
                                pointRadius: 1,
                                fill: false,
                            },
                            {
                                label: "Value",
                                order: 1,
                                data: counts[i][0],
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.85)',
                                borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.85)',
                                borderWidth: 2,
                                pointRadius: 3,
                                fill: false,
                            },
                {
                                label: "Prediction",
                                order: 1,
                                data: counts[i][2],
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.85)',
                                borderColor: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.85)',
                                borderWidth: 2,
                                pointRadius: 3,
                                fill: false,
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                    options: {
            
                                pan: {
                                 enabled: true,
                                 mode: 'xy'
                                 },
                                zoom: {
                                 enabled: true,
                                 drag: true,
                                 speed: 0.1,
                                 threshold: 2,
                                 mode: 'xy'
                                },
            title:{
                  text: "Behaviours",
                  display: true,
                      fontSize: 15
                },
            legend: {
                    display: false},
            elements: {center:{}},
                        responsive: true,
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Date & Time'}}],
                            yAxes: [{scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Parameter Values'},ticks: {beginAtZero: true}}]
                        }
                    },
                });console.log(myChart);
        document.getElementById("main2").appendChild(divname);
        document.getElementById(divname.id).appendChild(_canvas);
        document.getElementById(_canvas.id).appendChild(dataname);
            };

}
```

Does anybody point my mistake so I can remove that annoying undefined watermark?

The graph is generated with the array coming from serverside, and if more than 1 array is found in counts then counts.length amounts o graphs are generated without any erorrs except that undefined mark on each graph.

Pan and zoom is not working as well but I think I have to ask another question for that.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
counts =[[2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 8, 3, 9, 20, 3, 10, 14, 9, 4, 11, 26, 17, 22, 17, 8, 11, 14, 0, 1, 10, 20, 32, 39, 41, 15, 25, 36, 3, 3, 4, 9, 8, 12, 6, 5, 8, 4, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 0, 4, 7, 13, 4, 1, 4, 3, 14, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 7, 1, 3, 3, 8, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3, 3, 6, 3, 5, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 24, 28, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 6, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4, 2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3, 8, 3, 3],
[ Decimal('-5.02379'), Decimal('-4.99941'), Decimal('-4.50109'), Decimal('-4.69107'), Decimal('-5.79913'), Decimal('-5.32389'), Decimal('-4.47361'), Decimal('-5.26524'), Decimal('-5.23322'), Decimal('-3.63338'), Decimal('-4.58475'), Decimal('-6.06872'), Decimal('-5.62456'), Decimal('-4.22436'), Decimal('-4.56806'), Decimal('-5.19584'), Decimal('-5.25142'), Decimal('-5.32266'), Decimal('-4.28239'), Decimal('-5.32152'), Decimal('-6.29455'), Decimal('-4.59444'), Decimal('-4.58253'), Decimal('-5.78550'), Decimal('-5.04559'), Decimal('-4.94003'), Decimal('-3.49258'), Decimal('-1.70510'), Decimal('-4.22833'), Decimal('-3.52883'), Decimal('2.32241'), Decimal('-2.35649'), Decimal('-5.28643'), Decimal('0.77526'), Decimal('-0.21235'), Decimal('-3.89572'), Decimal('-1.22256'), Decimal('6.30103'), Decimal('5.53760'), Decimal('5.53476'), Decimal('7.52865'), Decimal('2.21410'), Decimal('2.29482'), Decimal('4.93989'), Decimal('-1.07637'), Decimal('-3.65299'), Decimal('1.13108'), Decimal('5.06221'), Decimal('11.38730'), Decimal('17.05850'), Decimal('20.76260'), Decimal('8.39483'), Decimal('10.55110'), Decimal('22.61550'), Decimal('5.46830'), Decimal('-0.54232'), Decimal('1.68621'), Decimal('2.62207'), Decimal('1.28697'), Decimal('2.57310'), Decimal('-0.59782'), Decimal('-2.52453'), Decimal('-1.09690'), Decimal('-3.52609'), Decimal('-5.18571'), Decimal('-4.88903'), Decimal('-3.62987'), Decimal('-4.72965'), Decimal('-6.75096'), Decimal('-7.58061'), Decimal('-7.34248'), Decimal('-6.54829'), Decimal('-7.60781'), Decimal('-7.50315'), Decimal('-8.84574'), Decimal('-7.40102'), Decimal('-5.46129'), Decimal('-2.44954'), Decimal('-6.13441'), Decimal('-8.44340'), Decimal('-6.61738'), Decimal('-6.95528'), Decimal('-2.19336'), Decimal('-5.66007'), Decimal('-7.11027'), Decimal('-6.73448'), Decimal('-6.56465'), Decimal('-7.58405'), Decimal('-7.41519'), Decimal('-5.39759'), Decimal('-7.98707'), Decimal('-7.85621'), Decimal('-7.34767'), Decimal('-5.38887'), Decimal('-7.50762'), Decimal('-7.61573'), Decimal('-7.66213'), Decimal('-6.79566'), Decimal('-7.09190'), Decimal('-5.43439'), Decimal('-5.88845'), Decimal('-7.76656'), Decimal('-8.25114'), Decimal('-7.21203'), Decimal('-6.35874'), Decimal('-5.86959'), Decimal('-4.81169'), Decimal('-6.05118'), Decimal('-6.55131'), Decimal('-5.17711'), Decimal('-6.05328'), Decimal('-5.60891'), Decimal('-6.51707'), Decimal('-6.61051'), Decimal('-7.78867'), Decimal('-7.97757'), Decimal('-8.40487'), Decimal('1.02573'), Decimal('7.08680'), Decimal('-3.98514'), Decimal('-4.54250'), Decimal('-4.01628'), Decimal('-5.68370'), Decimal('-5.46256'), Decimal('-5.09368'), Decimal('-6.21006'), Decimal('-5.11244'), Decimal('-4.94492'), Decimal('-6.86292'), Decimal('-7.18263'), Decimal('-7.73950'), Decimal('-7.62207'), Decimal('-8.21234'), Decimal('-8.46901'), Decimal('-6.75024'), Decimal('-6.99760'), Decimal('-7.03625'), Decimal('-7.81642'), Decimal('-6.11583'), Decimal('-5.79499'), Decimal('-7.57666'), Decimal('-7.71903'), Decimal('-7.28183'), Decimal('-5.08020'), Decimal('-6.99838')], [Decimal('9.94791'), Decimal('9.98058'), Decimal('10.46990'), Decimal('10.27960'), Decimal('9.18582'), Decimal('9.65369'), Decimal('10.49650'), Decimal('9.71640'), Decimal('9.72258'), Decimal('11.32870'), Decimal('10.40170'), Decimal('8.92187'), Decimal('9.37201'), Decimal('10.73210'), Decimal('10.38960'), Decimal('9.76525'), Decimal('9.70999'), Decimal('9.62846'), Decimal('10.66740'), Decimal('9.63372'), Decimal('8.65963'), Decimal('10.36630'), Decimal('10.38040'), Decimal('9.18541'), Decimal('9.92102'), Decimal('10.01480'), Decimal('11.50860'), Decimal('13.32200'), Decimal('10.81450'), Decimal('11.57650'), Decimal('17.92330'), Decimal('13.33680'), Decimal('10.44450'), Decimal('16.80440'), Decimal('15.82140'), Decimal('12.14720'), Decimal('14.90680'), Decimal('23.08330'), Decimal('22.32770'), Decimal('22.34240'), Decimal('24.35300'), Decimal('19.14770'), Decimal('19.23020'), Decimal('21.88420'), Decimal('16.16900'), Decimal('13.66310'), Decimal('18.48850'), Decimal('22.54550'), Decimal('29.39600'), Decimal('35.51820'), Decimal('39.39600'), Decimal('27.40230'), Decimal('29.62130'), Decimal('42.02920'), Decimal('25.99800'), Decimal('20.22650'), Decimal('22.50060'), Decimal('23.40670'), Decimal('22.10460'), Decimal('23.38850'), Decimal('20.26890'), Decimal('18.35720'), Decimal('19.78110'), Decimal('17.39220'), Decimal('15.75140'), Decimal('16.05070'), Decimal('17.31020'), Decimal('16.20940'), Decimal('14.20010'), Decimal('13.38010'), Decimal('13.61940'), Decimal('14.41380'), Decimal('13.35810'), Decimal('13.45770'), Decimal('12.12770'), Decimal('13.58010'), Decimal('15.53700'), Decimal('18.63790'), Decimal('14.97470'), Decimal('12.68040'), Decimal('14.51110'), Decimal('14.13970'), Decimal('19.05020'), Decimal('15.61050'), Decimal('14.16140'), Decimal('14.53250'), Decimal('14.66620'), Decimal('13.64820'), Decimal('13.79750'), Decimal('15.82270'), Decimal('13.21160'), Decimal('13.32910'), Decimal('13.78200'), Decimal('15.56840'), Decimal('13.31110'), Decimal('13.05690'), Decimal('12.93760'), Decimal('13.46010'), Decimal('13.11120'), Decimal('14.76770'), Decimal('14.29330'), Decimal('12.38460'), Decimal('11.46900'), Decimal('12.38720'), Decimal('12.82150'), Decimal('13.30390'), Decimal('14.37800'), Decimal('13.12750'), Decimal('12.56640'), Decimal('13.93010'), Decimal('13.05690'), Decimal('13.40700'), Decimal('12.50060'), Decimal('12.40380'), Decimal('11.23860'), Decimal('11.04710'), Decimal('10.62180'), Decimal('20.87000'), Decimal('27.34260'), Decimal('16.50340'), Decimal('16.08300'), Decimal('16.60300'), Decimal('14.94990'), Decimal('15.05020'), Decimal('15.41590'), Decimal('14.30570'), Decimal('15.40340'), Decimal('15.55870'), Decimal('13.65000'), Decimal('13.32820'), Decimal('12.72640'), Decimal('12.84370'), Decimal('12.24610'), Decimal('11.99100'), Decimal('13.72490'), Decimal('13.47770'), Decimal('13.43960'), Decimal('12.66120'), Decimal('14.37990'), Decimal('14.70500'), Decimal('12.93100'), Decimal('12.78710'), Decimal('13.22200'), Decimal('15.45430'), Decimal('13.53570')],
[ Decimal('2.46206'), Decimal('2.49059'), Decimal('2.98443'), Decimal('2.79425'), Decimal('1.69334'), Decimal('2.16490'), Decimal('3.01146'), Decimal('2.22558'), Decimal('2.24468'), Decimal('3.84765'), Decimal('2.90847'), Decimal('1.42657'), Decimal('1.87373'), Decimal('3.25388'), Decimal('2.91079'), Decimal('2.28470'), Decimal('2.22928'), Decimal('2.15290'), Decimal('3.19253'), Decimal('2.15610'), Decimal('1.18254'), Decimal('2.88595'), Decimal('2.89893'), Decimal('1.69995'), Decimal('2.43771'), Decimal('2.53738'), Decimal('4.00799'), Decimal('5.80846'), Decimal('3.29309'), Decimal('4.02385'), Decimal('10.12290'), Decimal('5.49017'), Decimal('2.57901'), Decimal('8.78984'), Decimal('7.80454'), Decimal('4.12572'), Decimal('6.84214'), Decimal('14.69220'), Decimal('13.93260'), Decimal('13.93860'), Decimal('15.94080'), Decimal('10.68090'), Decimal('10.76250'), Decimal('13.41210'), Decimal('7.54633'), Decimal('5.00506'), Decimal('9.80978'), Decimal('13.80380'), Decimal('20.39160'), Decimal('26.28830'), Decimal('30.07930'), Decimal('17.89860'), Decimal('20.08620'), Decimal('32.32240'), Decimal('15.73310'), Decimal('9.84210'), Decimal('12.09340'), Decimal('13.01440'), Decimal('11.69580'), Decimal('12.98080'), Decimal('9.83557'), Decimal('7.91631'), Decimal('9.34208'), Decimal('6.93307'), Decimal('5.28285'), Decimal('5.58085'), Decimal('6.84017'), Decimal('5.73990'), Decimal('3.72457'), Decimal('2.89974'), Decimal('3.13847'), Decimal('3.93276'), Decimal('2.87517'), Decimal('2.97728'), Decimal('1.64099'), Decimal('3.08955'), Decimal('5.03786'), Decimal('8.09416'), Decimal('4.42012'), Decimal('2.11851'), Decimal('3.94687'), Decimal('3.59219'), Decimal('8.42840'), Decimal('4.97522'), Decimal('3.52558'), Decimal('3.89902'), Decimal('4.05077'), Decimal('3.03207'), Decimal('3.19117'), Decimal('5.21256'), Decimal('2.61228'), Decimal('2.73646'), Decimal('3.21716'), Decimal('5.08978'), Decimal('2.90171'), Decimal('2.72061'), Decimal('2.63775'), Decimal('3.33224'), Decimal('3.00965'), Decimal('4.66666'), Decimal('4.20244'), Decimal('2.30902'), Decimal('1.60894'), Decimal('2.58757'), Decimal('3.23135'), Decimal('3.71718'), Decimal('4.78314'), Decimal('3.53814'), Decimal('3.00754'), Decimal('4.37649'), Decimal('3.50183'), Decimal('3.89907'), Decimal('2.99177'), Decimal('2.89664'), Decimal('1.72496'), Decimal('1.53474'), Decimal('1.10846'), Decimal('10.94790'), Decimal('17.21470'), Decimal('6.25915'), Decimal('5.77024'), Decimal('6.29337'), Decimal('4.63308'), Decimal('4.79381'), Decimal('5.16111'), Decimal('4.04784'), Decimal('5.14547'), Decimal('5.30690'), Decimal('3.39354'), Decimal('3.07277'), Decimal('2.49346'), Decimal('2.61080'), Decimal('2.01689'), Decimal('1.76100'), Decimal('3.48735'), Decimal('3.24005'), Decimal('3.20165'), Decimal('2.42237'), Decimal('4.13206'), Decimal('4.45499'), Decimal('2.67716'), Decimal('2.53404'), Decimal('2.97008'), Decimal('5.18703'), Decimal('3.26866')],
[ '2021-12-25 06:35', '2021-12-25 06:40', '2021-12-25 06:45', '2021-12-25 06:50', '2021-12-25 06:55', '2021-12-25 07:00', '2021-12-25 07:05', '2021-12-25 07:10', '2021-12-25 07:15', '2021-12-25 07:20', '2021-12-25 07:25', '2021-12-25 07:30', '2021-12-25 07:35', '2021-12-25 07:40', '2021-12-25 07:45', '2021-12-25 07:50', '2021-12-25 07:55', '2021-12-25 08:00', '2021-12-25 08:05', '2021-12-25 08:10', '2021-12-25 08:15', '2021-12-25 08:20', '2021-12-25 08:25', '2021-12-25 08:30', '2021-12-25 08:35', '2021-12-25 08:40', '2021-12-25 08:45', '2021-12-25 08:50', '2021-12-25 08:55', '2021-12-25 09:00', '2021-12-25 09:05', '2021-12-25 09:10', '2021-12-25 09:15', '2021-12-25 09:20', '2021-12-25 09:25', '2021-12-25 09:30', '2021-12-25 09:35', '2021-12-25 09:40', '2021-12-25 09:45', '2021-12-25 09:50', '2021-12-25 09:55', '2021-12-25 10:00', '2021-12-25 10:05', '2021-12-25 10:10', '2021-12-25 10:15', '2021-12-25 10:20', '2021-12-25 10:25', '2021-12-25 10:30', '2021-12-25 10:35', '2021-12-25 10:40', '2021-12-25 10:45', '2021-12-25 10:50', '2021-12-25 10:55', '2021-12-25 11:00', '2021-12-25 11:05', '2021-12-25 11:10', '2021-12-25 11:15', '2021-12-25 11:20', '2021-12-25 11:25', '2021-12-25 11:30', '2021-12-25 11:35', '2021-12-25 11:40', '2021-12-25 11:45', '2021-12-25 11:50', '2021-12-25 11:55', '2021-12-25 12:00', '2021-12-25 12:05', '2021-12-25 12:10', '2021-12-25 12:15', '2021-12-25 12:20', '2021-12-25 12:25', '2021-12-25 12:30', '2021-12-25 12:35', '2021-12-25 12:40', '2021-12-25 12:45', '2021-12-25 12:50', '2021-12-25 12:55', '2021-12-25 13:00', '2021-12-25 13:05', '2021-12-25 13:10', '2021-12-25 13:15', '2021-12-25 13:20', '2021-12-25 13:25', '2021-12-25 13:30', '2021-12-25 13:35', '2021-12-25 13:40', '2021-12-25 13:45', '2021-12-25 13:50', '2021-12-25 13:55', '2021-12-25 14:00', '2021-12-25 14:05', '2021-12-25 14:10', '2021-12-25 14:15', '2021-12-25 14:20', '2021-12-25 14:25', '2021-12-25 14:30', '2021-12-25 14:35', '2021-12-25 14:40', '2021-12-25 14:45', '2021-12-25 14:50', '2021-12-25 14:55', '2021-12-25 15:00', '2021-12-25 15:05', '2021-12-25 15:10', '2021-12-25 15:15', '2021-12-25 15:20', '2021-12-25 15:25', '2021-12-25 15:30', '2021-12-25 15:35', '2021-12-25 15:40', '2021-12-25 15:45', '2021-12-25 15:50', '2021-12-25 15:55', '2021-12-25 16:00', '2021-12-25 16:05', '2021-12-25 16:10', '2021-12-25 16:15', '2021-12-25 16:20', '2021-12-25 16:25', '2021-12-25 16:30', '2021-12-25 16:35', '2021-12-25 16:40', '2021-12-25 16:45', '2021-12-25 16:50', '2021-12-25 16:55', '2021-12-25 17:00', '2021-12-25 17:05', '2021-12-25 17:10', '2021-12-25 17:15', '2021-12-25 17:20', '2021-12-25 17:25', '2021-12-25 17:30', '2021-12-25 17:35', '2021-12-25 17:40', '2021-12-25 17:45', '2021-12-25 17:50', '2021-12-25 17:55', '2021-12-25 18:00', '2021-12-25 18:05', '2021-12-25 18:10', '2021-12-25 18:15', '2021-12-25 18:20', '2021-12-25 18:25', '2021-12-25 18:30', '2021-12-25 18:35']]
```

Comment: Why are you creating a canvas of each item in the counts? can you share a data sample?

Comment: Why do you think this is because of multiple canvases? Due to selection there can be multiple graphs to be generated. That is why for each count array JS creates new canvas and div. - Added sample count to question

Comment: Yes, i think you only need one canvas

Comment: Actually I have managed to solve it. The problem is  here: elements: {center:{}}, so I have changed it to : elements:{center:{text:""}}, and now it is good to go if anyone experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Great to hear that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have managed to solve it.

The problem is here:
elements: {center:{}},

so I have changed it to :
elements:{center:{text:""}},

and now it is good to go if anyone experiencing the same issue.